# your project contains error(s) please fix before running

Tags: android

I am developing a simple android application But when I run eclipse tell me the

```
 error:Your project contains error(s), please fix it before running it.
```

I can't find any error in my project or there is not have error in my application.

```
 *there is red exclamatory mark under the project name.*
```

plz help me!!

Comment: Go to `Window -> Show View -> Problems`. When that window comes up, it will show you a list of errors and warnings in your projects. You can then double click on them to go right to them to see what they are.

Comment: clean ur project and than try it

Answer (score 1):

The red exclamation mark:

[image]

means Eclipse is having trouble finding a required library or source.  If you are using any 3rd party libraries make sure they are included in your .classpath (this can be setup in your project properties).  If that checks out and the problem persists, make sure Eclipse knows where to find your Android SDK.

And after all that, make sure to clean your project, then *Fix Project Properties* by right clicking on your project, and finally trying to run the project.

Comment: No, the *big red exclamation mark* is different from the *red box with a white* x. This is what I assume the OP is referring to: http://i.imgur.com/tGOlD.png

Answer (score 0):

Try these steps..

**1.** Clean your project

**2.** Check you have not used any Uppercase or special symbol except"_"(underscore) in resources names.

**3.** If you are implementing any library projects or jar, see they are included in the Build Path..

**4.** Check is there any problem in the layouts, check the xml codes..

getFetchedData() Check the R file, is it showing any error, (ie red marked lines under integer constants)